# Deriving from PXGraph multiple time

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'd like to have some common logic shared between two screens, so I want to have an abstract class inheriting from PXGraph, and then two different Graphs inheriting from this abstract class.

Like this :

```
namespace LE
{
    public abstract class ICarrySomeLogic : PXGraph<ICarrySomeLogic>
    {
        // common business logic
    }

    public class graph1 : ICarrySomeLogic
    {
        // specific business logic
    }

    public class graph2 : ICarrySomeLogic
    {
        // specific business logic
    }
}
```

Does it work correctly ? Is there a "best practice" or another proper way to do it ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before and works great. Here is my example simplified...

```
public abstract class MyGraphBase<TGraph, TPrimary, TWhere> : PXGraph<TGraph, TPrimary> 
    where TGraph : PXGraph 
    where TPrimary : class, IBqlTable, new()
    where TWhere : class, IBqlWhere, new()
{
    public PXSelect<TPrimary, TWhere> document;
}

public class GraphOneEntry : MyGraphBase<GraphOneEntry, MyDac, Where<MyDac.docType, Equal<DocType.typeOne>>>
{
}

public class GraphTwoEntry : MyGraphBase<GraphTwoEntry, MyDac, Where<MyDac.docType, Equal<DocType.typeTwo>>>
{
}
```

My events in the base abstract class will fire and I can override as needed in the other graphs.

I have been using this since version 5.3

**Edit:** starting in 2017R2 there is a new concept around [Reusable Business Logic](https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bbc04253-7686-41dd-898b-aca47c1c6789) that can also be utilized for this same purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a solution to make this a bit cleaner : my TWhere is quite long ?   public class ProcessLettrage : ProcessLettering<ProcessLettrage, ARRegister, Where2<
                Where<ARRegisterLeExt.lettrageCD, IsNull,
            And<Current<LettrageFilter.branchID>, Equal<ARRegister.branchID>,
                And<Current<LettrageFilter.accountID>,
                   ...
                            >>>>>

Comment: Is your primary view ("document in the example) the same for both graphs?

Comment: The TPrimary is not the same. One is ARRegister, the other APRegister, but the logic behind will be the same.

Comment: you could try to get rid of the primary view "document" from the base class and move it to the inherited classes. Then you could remove the TWhere. I think you still need the TPrimary for call to PXGraph unless you wireup all of the "buttons" in the inherited graph such as PXSave, etc.If you decompile PXGraph<TGraph, TPrimary> you can see all of the calls if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have given should do what you need. The inheritable traits and behavior of your abstract class will be inherited by your subclasses as expected.  This works for extension classes as well.  If you extend an existing Graph, you can then subclass your extension class to achieve inheritance.

Note: The "I" prefix for type naming is a standard in C# for interfaces, not classes. Even though abstract classes have some similarities to interfaces, they are not the same. If you want to follow Microsoft best practices, you might consider not using this prefix for class naming. If your I prefix is simply meant as the word "I" (as in you, yourself), then you can just ignore this note. :)